# how is a java program compiled and run?

Tags: java, jvm

The question is very broad , but i wanted to go under-the-hood..I can write and run java programs,but still what puzzles me is how the overall program is implemented.We have the compiler which converts the program into bytecode for the JVM. And how does the JVM allocate memory ? Does JVM have a built in heap and stack or does the interpreter of the JVM allocate memory to the object in the main memory itself.
Forgive me for my ignorance...but this really puzzles me.

Thanks in advance..
Sriram

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine ?

Answer (score 3):

- `.java` file is converted from human readable form to `byte code` using `Java Compiler`.
- `JVM` **loads** the class (loading is done before initialization).
- `JVM` also take care about the `creation` and `management` of `String Literals` during this time.
- When the `class` is instantiated, the `instance` is given **memory space** by `JVM` on the `heap`, along with `hashCode`, which depends on the **memory location** assigned by `JVM`.

Comment: the automatic garbage collector works inside the JVM..how is it able to work when the object is allocated space in the heap of the RAM...does it access the memory locations prescribed by the JVM?

Comment: in `a=object` `a` is an `Object Reference Variable` which is a 64bit value, which points to the Actual object on the Heap......

Comment: sorry for the a=..i have edited my post