# Does the Hotspot JVM Compile the code to machine code or simply runs it

Tags: java, jvm, jit

To simplify the question, lets assume that in our JRE we have a Hotspot JVM implementation that doesn't use JIT.
Meaning we won't have machine code precompiled.

I am trying to understand, the JVM when it encounters byte code, does the interpreter uses the Hotspot compiler to compile the code to machine code and only then can the JVM run the code?
Or does the interpreter simply runs the code as the JVM has some kind of native methods that correspond to each byte code command?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340603/how-is-a-java-program-compiled-and-run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Meaning we won't have machine code precompiled.

The above sentence of yours indicates your misunderstanding of what the JIT compiler is. It doesn't compile code ahead of time, but just in time, hence its name.

This makes the rest of your question harder to understand because the "HotSpot compiler" is the JIT compiler.

But, to sum this up for you: in a normal case, HotSpot begins by interpreting the bytecode, then JIT-compiles those pieces whose runtime profiling data indicates that they are the "hot spots", being executed a lot (default threshold is 10,000 passes over a piece of code).

If you disable JIT compiling, HotSpot will indeed just interpret all of the Java bytecode.

Comment: Excelent Answer! I have been trying to figure out from so many sources and non was as clear as yours
To clarify: HotSpot is a version of JVM which uses the JIT compiler, (which is as its name suggest a Just In Time compilation)
Meaning during run if the JVM find some methods that are executed a lot it will optimize the run time by using the JIT to compile them to machine code and then run these methods.
So there is no other compiler! for the JVM,  and the JVM actually runs byte code if its not using the JIT.
Am I correct?

Also how does it run the byte code/ do we have a set of native methods?